# onmouseover getting the id of a list item which refers to a mysql table & populate a new list with the table rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I want to make a dynamic submenu which directly gets data from mysql table
I have this js to get the current list item id...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.courseTitle').mouseover(function() {
   var id=this.id;
 });
});
```

then I have one of the parent menu list item..

```
<li class="courseTitle" id="100"><a href="../courses/100/">Course100</li>
```

I want to get the id of the parent list item without page refresh. the submenu populating script is something like-

```
<ul id="chaptList">
   <?php $crsID=$_REQUEST['course'];
   require('../common/dbcon/courseCon.php');
   $chapt_count=mysql_query("select * from course_$crsID order by chapter_id");
```

MY Js snippet is getting the li element id nicely.. but I need to pass the id value to my php snippet somehow whenever mouseover occurs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to go for the old school method.. used simple arrays.. as I guess retreiving data from database on runtime every now n then is not that much of a good option

Answer (score 3):

How abt this:

```
    var id 
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.courseTitle').mouseover(function() {
       id = $(this).attr('id');
     });
    });
```

Comment: in case u haven't noticed i actually already did that as u can see in my js snippet.. I need the process for passing the value somehow to my php snippet.. my js snippet is getting the id nicely.. I want to somehow pass that value to my php snippet on each mouseover